# Двумерный массив в c#

Tags: c#, массивы

Перехожу с С++ на С# (универ).

Вот я начал делать двумерный массив, но его выводит в одну строку.

```
namespace Massive2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] mas;
            int i, j;

            Console.Write("Введите количество элементов массива n = ");
            string buf = Console.ReadLine();
            int n = int.Parse(buf);

            mas = new int[n,n];

            Random rand = new Random();

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i, j] = rand.Next(-100, 100));

            //for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            //{
            //    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            //        Console.Write("\t"+mas[i,j] );

            //}


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем проблема вставить после внутреннего цикла предложение

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

Например

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{  
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i, j] = rand.Next(-100, 100));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Это вообще законно? =D

Comment: @ArtikSlayer Что именно?

Comment: Ммм,я понял. Можно и так? Console.Write("\n");

Comment: @ArtikSlayer Да, можно и так. Но использование WriteLine более выразительно.

Comment: И последний доп. вопрос к этой теме. В чём разница между Console.Write и Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer Последняя вставляет символ новой строки в поток после вывода данных